# How to change user session status for all his devices away, dnd, etc

Tags: java, rabbitmq, xmpp, openfire

I create a messenger based on openfire. I can connect and set status on online / offline and the openfire console also changes, but I have a problem with my other devices.

Other devices (other users) gets information about changing my status and it's visible to them.

My devices (second and third device of the same user) do not see the status change and all are online. If I log on to the fourth device, information is sent to other devices (other users) that I am online, although I still have my status on the first device set as away.

Is there any plugin that allows updating the status on all devices of a given user?

Answer (score 0):

This should be done by the server as per [Server Processing of Outbound Initial Presence](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#presence-initial-outbound)

> The user's server MUST also broadcast initial presence from the user's newly available resource to all of the user's available resources, including the resource that generated the presence notification in the first place (i.e., an entity is implicitly subscribed to its own presence).

So each time you connect your own device (i.e. same username/JID) and send presence your server has to broadcast that presence to all already connected connected devices (same JID).

It looks like there was similar problem reported [OF-454Openfire does not send user presence information to all resources of the user](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-454) but it's marked as fixed: `Fix Version/s: 4.0.0`

If you are using cluster please make sure that your nodes can communicate without problems.

Comment: Yes, I receive this information on the second device, but the session status for the second device does not change. Is there anything else I need to do to set the session status on the other device to the one I received?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? On the second device you will be able to see status of that device and the status of the first device.

Comment: I solved this problem, but have another one. Can you please check if you can help also with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000777/how-to-delete-a-message-from-group-chat-in-xmppopenfire

Comment: Please share explanation to your problem, please also clarify what's missing from above answer.