# How to delete a message from group chat in XMPP(Openfire)?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire

I want to delete single group chat message from openfire history. Is it possible?

The history is not saved in the OfMessageArchive table, after deleting the message in the application the message disappears, but after re-logging is downloaded from the (base?) of Openfire and it's still visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until now you cant delete single messages. There is an Extension planned (http://legastero.github.io/customxeps/extensions/message-delete.html) but it's not yet supported.

The only possibility is to delete the whole conversation, since messages are not stored separately.